# Convert JavaScript ES6 function into ES3

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array that I successfully transform into a string format with an EcmaScript-6 function. However, how can I do this using EcmaScript-3? The receiving endpoint requires an ES3 function.

**Original array:**

```
formdata: [
    1: {name: "gender", value: "F", focus: 0, type: "radio"}
    2: {name: "firstname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
    3: {name: "lastname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
    4: {name: "birthday", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
    5: {name: "street", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
    6: {name: "streetNo", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"}
]
```

**Required string format**

```
let formdata = gender.radio|F|0;firstName.text|empty|1;lastName.text|empty|0;street.text|empty|0;houseNumber.text|empty|0;zip.text|empty|0;city.text|empty|0;country.select-one|de|0;birthdate-day.text|empty|0;birthdate-month.text|empty|0;birthdate-year.text|empty|0;email.email|empty|0;code.text|filled_out|0
```

**My working solution with ES6:**

```
let res = formdata.map(({name,value,focus,type}) => `${name}.${type}|${value}|${focus}`).join(';')
```

**My take on converting to ES3:**

```
var res = formdata.map(({name,value,focus,type}) { 
  ("name" + "." + "type" + "|" + "value" + "focus").join(;)
}
```

This solution is obviously not working and also I am not sure whether it is valid ES3 JavaScript.

Thanks!

Comment: Use Babel.js to convert ES6 to older versions.

Comment: `map` is added in ES5, so that will obviously create a problem. You can use a simple `for` loop to iterate over the array, and create the string.

Comment: You original array is not valid JavaScript. Nor is the "required string format" and ES3 version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issues with your ES3 attempt:

- The arrow function is missing the arrow, but is also an ES6 addition to the syntax
- `.join(;)` is not valid JavaScript. `.join(";")` is.
- destructuring syntax was introduced in ES6
- `.map` was introduced in ES5
- You need one more "|"

So:

```js
var formdata = [{name: "gender", value: "F", focus: 0, type: "radio"},{name: "firstname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"},{name: "lastname", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"},    {name: "birthday", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"},{name: "street", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"},{name: "streetNo", value: "empty", focus: 0, type: "text"},];

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < formdata.length; i++) {
    var elem = formdata[i];
    arr.push(elem.name + "." + elem.type + "|" + elem.value + "|" + elem.focus);
}
var str = arr.join(";");

console.log(str);
```